# Vim configure for omnicompletion and ctags problems

Tags: c++, vim, ctags

I am just beginning using vim for half a month, since I want to use it to code C++, I just install the omnicompletion to auto complete the code.

However, when I follow the instruction on the omnicppcomplete.txt, (I downloaded the Exuberant Ctags and installed using "./configure && make && sudo make install" command), I found it still pops out the error(ctags -R illegal command), to avoid using the ctags that my mac already have, I add the "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" in my .zshrc file, and add "let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/usr/local/bin/ctags'" in my .vimrc file.

However, I still can not run the command "ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .", with the error illegal ctags -R.
Can anyone help with that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you run the command from vim or from the shell? What's the output of `:echo $PATH` in Vim and `$ echo $PATH` in your shell?

Comment: I run these command in my shell(zsh), and when I run the echo $PATH, the result is echo $PATH                                         
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbinThank you! @romainl

Comment: While in Vim, it turns out to be an invalid command for echo $PATH

Comment: That's strange. `:echo $PATH` is a "classic". Try `:echo $` followed by `<tab>` to see all the available environment variables.

Comment: Oops,I may made a mistake last time, I tried it in vim and it shows like this: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin@romainl

Comment: Well, I'm lost. Did you open a new shell after the installation? Try `$ which ctags` and/or `$ /usr/local/bin/ctags` in your shell. If it can't find `ctags` it means that you screwed the installation.

Comment: the ctags are there. But I found the ctags exist in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin.@romainl

Comment: I completely missed it, sorry. You only need to edit manually your `$PATH in your `.*rc  so that `/usr/local/bin` is searched before `/usr/bin`

Comment: Hi, I followed your method and it works now, but another problem is that the omnicomplete can only auto complete the std:: functions. While I create a class, it can not help to auto complete the member function. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks a lot for your great help!@romainl

Comment: Forget omnicppcomplete, go to clang_complete instead. Instructions on the official [website](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) and [here](http://blog.msoares.pro.br/archives/quick-recipe-to-enable-clang_complete-on-vim)

Answer (score 1):

The point is you're on the mac and should use mac-ports to override the osx standard ctags, not a custom build of your ctags. This should get you back on track

- Uninstall the ctags you've built from the source: In the src dir where you build it try to

  `sudo make uninstall`
- Open a new shell after installing ports (to load your new system config from .profile/.zshrc etc..)
- Next, install ctags from the port repository, so first install [Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/), then install ctags via ports:

  `sudo port install ctags`
- If you've used the default install location for ports, your shell-rc file should point PATH to `/opt/local/bin`. Your ctags (with -R support) should be in (`/opt/local/bin/ctags`), but to make 100% sure check where your system finds it by typing:

  `which ctags`

  should give you

  `/opt/local/bin/ctags`
- Now check your PATH from within vim (`:echo $PATH`), which should prepend the ports directory (/opt/local/bin).

To test code completion (not the Auto-Completion) from within vim (assumed vim is pointed to a proper `:tags` file, read help on :tags) you don't need to install anything.

- Just type `Ctrl-N` in insert mode, and a list of possible identifiers should pop up.